# Compute the integral by changing to cylindrical coordinates.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

[Question Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS6al.png)

After converting to cylindrical coordinates:

The limits of integration that I got are $0\le z \le 1 + r, 0\le r \le 2,0\le \theta \le 2\pi$

After solving the last integral I get is:
$(128/15)\int_0^{2\pi} cos\theta\,d\theta$

After solving the integral in the end I get zero. I think the limits of integration for $\theta$ are wrong. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The limits $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ give you integration over a complete disk around the origin, including positive and negative $x$ coordinates
and positive and negative $y$ coordinates.
But the original integral has $x \geq 0$ and $y\geq 0,$
no negative $x$ or $y$ coordinates.

Eliminate all parts of your integral that have negative $x$ or $y$
coordinates, that is, eliminate every $\theta$ such that
either $\cos\theta < 0$ or $\sin\theta < 0$. What is left should give you a positive integral.

Comment: so, between 0 and pi/2 ? since we'd be in the first quadrant.

Comment: Yes, that should work.